# Copy subfolders to another folder in VB.NET without overwriting

Tags: vb.net, recursion, copy, overwrite

I have this code which I am using to copy a directory:

```
Private Sub CopyDirectory(ByVal sourcePath As String, ByVal destPath As String)
    If Not Directory.Exists(destPath) Then
        Directory.CreateDirectory(destPath)
    End If

    For Each file1 As String In Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath)
        Dim dest As String = Path.Combine(destPath, Path.GetFileName(file1))
        File.Copy(file1, dest)
    Next

    For Each dir1 As String In Directory.GetDirectories(Path.GetDirectoryName(sourcePath))
        Dim destdir As String = Path.Combine(destPath, Path.GetFileName(dir1))
        CopyDirectory(dir1, destdir)
    Next
End Sub
```

And this is how I call `CopyDirectory` method:

```
 Dim sourcepath As String = "E:\Crazy\"
 Dim DestPath As String = "D:\Snippets\"
 CopyDirectory(sourcepath, DestPath,)
```

The problem is that it continously copies the folder again and again. How do I stop this? And how do I copy the subfolder a single time? I have used recursion.

Comment: AnyBody Please help me..

Answer (score 6):

Your problem lies here:

```
For Each dir1 As String In Directory.GetDirectories(Path.GetDirectoryName(sourcePath))
```

This will get the parent folder of the destPath, not the correct path to copy from.
Also, you have a problem with [File.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6cfw35a.aspx). If the file already exist in the destination path, calling File.Copy without an explict request to overwrite the destination will throw an exception.

```
Private Sub CopyDirectory(ByVal sourcePath As String, ByVal destPath As String)  

    If Not Directory.Exists(destPath) Then
        Directory.CreateDirectory(destPath)
    End If

    For Each file1 As String In Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath)
        Dim dest As String = Path.Combine(destPath, Path.GetFileName(file1))
        File.Copy(file1, dest, True)  ' Added True here to force the an overwrite 
    Next

    ' Use directly the sourcePath passed in, not the parent of that path
    For Each dir1 As String In Directory.GetDirectories(sourcePath)
        Dim destdir As String = Path.Combine(destPath, Path.GetFileName(dir1))
        CopyDirectory(dir1, destdir)
    Next
End Sub
```